# How to write multiline function in ts-node repl? I'm working on ubuntu environment

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8, typescript1.6

I want to write below function in ts-node repl

```js
function   padLeft (value: string, padding: any) { 
     if  ( typeof  padding === "number") { 
         return  Array(padding + 1).join(" ") + value; 
    } 
     if  ( typeof  padding === "string") { 
         return  padding + value; 
    } 
     throw   new  Error(`Expected string or number, got '${padding}'.`); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using ts-node version 0.9.2 . Multi line feature was not there.
So I upgraded it to version 1.8.

```html
npm install -g tsun
```

The issue got resolved